# Binding a Bitmap Image Source to an image in my Local folder

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a list of images in my `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` folder. I want to display the first image in an Image control.

On my viewmodel class I have the following code:-

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
if (files.Count > 0)
{
    vm.SelectedImage = files[0].Name;
}
```

and my Xaml has the following code:

```
<Image>
       <Image.Source>
           <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding SelectedImage, Mode=OneWay}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
        </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

But I can't figure out the correct string to pass in to get the image to show - any help would be appreciated!

Ta

Ross

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to get IsoStore databinding to work is to databind Image.Source to the Path property, not the Name property.

```
private async void SetImage()
{
    var files = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();
    this.DataContext = files.First();
}
```

XAML Databinding:

```
 <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Path}" Width="100" Height="100" />
```

And here's a print screen of Image.Source showing up as StorageFile.Path:

[image: Image.Source showing up to StorageFile.Path]